# How to optimize query which count last rows up to a certain condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have table `test`:
create table test

```
(
    id         serial
        primary key,
    status_id  integer,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
    client_id  integer
);
```

and I need to count all last rows with `status_id` != 3 sorted by `created_at` desc.
Such table:

```
id, status_id, created_at, client_id
(1, 3, '2023-04-23 19:34:08.454000 +00:00', 2),
(2, 3, '2023-04-23 19:34:07.493000 +00:00', 2),
(3, 3, '2023-04-23 19:34:06.459000 +00:00', 2),
(4, 2, '2023-04-23 19:34:05.838000 +00:00', 2),
(5, 3, '2023-04-23 19:34:04.782000 +00:00', 2),
(6, 3, '2023-04-23 19:34:03.768000 +00:00', 2),
(7, 2, '2023-04-23 19:34:02.768000 +00:00', 2),
(8, 3, '2023-03-23 19:34:02.768000 +00:00', 1),
(9, 2, '2023-02-23 19:34:02.768000 +00:00', 1),
(10, 3, '2022-04-23 19:34:02.768000 +00:00', 1);
```

result for client with id 1 must be 3 and for client with id 2 will be 1:

```
client_id, count
    2,3
    1,1
```

I have this query:

```
select count(*), i.client_id
from public.test i
where i.created_at > (select x.created_at
                      from public.test x
                      where x.status_id != 3
                        and x.client_id = i.client_id
                      order by x.created_at desc
                      limit 1)
group by i.client_id;
```

its works but very slow.
tried this index:

```
create index test_status_id_client_id_created_at_index
on public.test (status_id, client_id, created_at);
```

but index does not help.

Is there a way to optimize and speed up this query, or will it be necessary to make some kind of application that will export this data in a ready-made form in small time intervals?

explain:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=12.80..12.85 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=0.149..0.152 rows=2 loops=1)
  Group Key: i.client_id
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.80..12.81 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.144..0.145 rows=4 loops=1)
        Sort Key: i.client_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on test i  (cost=0.00..12.77 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.054..0.091 rows=4 loops=1)
              Filter: (created_at > (SubPlan 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 6
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Limit  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=10)
                      ->  Sort  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=10)
                            Sort Key: x.created_at DESC
                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on test x  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=2 loops=10)
                                  Filter: ((status_id <> 3) AND (client_id = i.client_id))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 8
Planning Time: 0.826 ms
Execution Time: 0.314 ms
```

I use postgresql 14 version.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6a259/4)

Comment: Hi - can you explain what you mean by “count all last rows” , what’s a “last row”? Also, I think you have your results the wrong way round - the sqlfiddle shows the count for client 1 is 1, not 3

Comment: “Very slow” and then just 1.1 milliseconds for this query, don’t match.

Comment: Why are you using a sub-query? I don't understand the output you are trying to get?

Comment: The created at values in your question are in the opposite order to your fiddle. Attention to detail matters.

Comment: @FrankHeikens i cannot execute query in production database during thirty mins

Comment: @BenKoshy https://i.imgur.com/lT4E7KF.jpeg

Comment: @wisicoc this is very confusing for me. are we filtering with status_id = 3 or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd replace the correlated sub-query with a regular sub-query, and join on it.

```
SELECT
  last.client_id,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    client_id,
    MAX(created_at)   created_at
  FROM
    public.test
  WHERE
    status_id <> 3
  GROUP BY
    client_id
)
  AS last
INNER JOIN
  public.test
    ON  test.client_id  = last.client_id
    AND test.created_at > last.created_at
GROUP BY
  last.client_id;
```

Then ensure an index on `(client_id, created_at)` and a partial index on `(client_id, created_at) WHERE status_id <> 3`